# CAN I DISPLAY DATA FROM SQL TO A LABEL

Tags: sql, vb.net

How can I display the data from SQL WORKGROUP 2005 to my label in VB.NET?

So far this is what I have tried:

```vb
Private Sub Label6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label6.Click

    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim Conn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection("Label6=RATE")

    strSQL = SELECT * FROM [PESORATE]

    Dim catCMD As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(strSQL, Conn)

    Conn.Open()

    Dim myReader As OdbcDataReader = catCMD.ExecuteReader()

    If myReader.HasRows Then
        Do While myReader.Read()
            'the SqlDataReader returns typed data.  You must use the
            'proper get method for the type you are retrieving.
            '(GetInt32, GetString, GetBoolean etc.)
            Write(myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal([Rate]))))
            Write("<BR>")
        Loop
    Else
        Write("No records found!")
    End If

    myReader.Close()
    Conn.Close()
```

Comment: WHAT ISN'T WORKING WITH YOUR CODE?

Comment: THE DATA IN THE SQL DOES NOT DISPLAY IN THE LABEL IN VB.NET

Comment: MY QUESTION IS HOW CAN I CALL THE DATA IN THE SQL TO BE DISPLAY IN THE LABEL

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string seems incorrect:

```
Dim Conn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection("Label6=RATE")
```

You need to correct it to point to an existing DSN or create a DSN less connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the piece of coding

Label6.text = your data